# MacBook Pro (Late 2008) 8GB RAM not being used

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, memory

I have the following:
 - MacBook Pro (Late 2008)
 - MacBookPro5,1
 - Boot ROM: MBP51.007E.B06.
 - OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

I upgraded RAM from 2GB to 8GB 1067MHz DDR3.

The system recognizes the 8GB memory since System Information reports:

- Bank 0/DIMM0 4 GB
- Bank 0/DIMM1 4 GB

To me, the system is still seeming slow and utilizing only 2GB RAM. In the Activity Monitor shows 1.75GB Memory used (App Mem: 707MB, Wired: 739MB), 1.21GB Cache.

How can I make sure the system is using the 8GB RAM?

Comment: If you open system information - what specifically shows for the two memory slots? I've seen a bank go missing and need to be repaired or reseated, but splitting a 4 GB chip in half seems odd. Unless you really have a pair of 1 GB chips - getting to 2 seems an odd result!

Comment: It shows 2 lines: Bank 0/DIMM0  4GB and Bank 0/DIMM1 4GB

Comment: RAM isn't going make a system run faster in all circumstances. You probably know this. But your posted stats there already show it using about two and a half gigabytes of RAM (Cache *is* used RAM—it's material that is no longer in active use, but OS X is keeping it around for quick reference if it's needed). The best measure of whether OS X is "using" RAM was to restart, and after a few hours of normal use check the Page Outs in Activity Monitor. But I see now that feature has been removed from Yosemite and later. Do you have any evidence that your system *is* swapping to disk?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be swapping.  I started multiple apps (mail, calendar, open office, Messages, Skype, MyPublisher, Photos) and the Memory used went up to 3.3GB while the cache is at 3.8GB. However the system still seems to be slow. The hard disk 250GB capacity and 166GB available.